# Where to park e-scooters at hotels?

Tags: hotels, scooters, electric-kickbikes

- Is it generally allowed to bring them to the rooms? They could be very dirty.
- Can you put them in the baggage room?
- Or does most hotels want you to put them on the street? How do you then recharge them?

I've never done this and am considering buying an electric scooter (kickbike type) to get to and from the hotels I stay at.

I've done research about baby strollers and bicycles but that didn't yield much either.

[image: Electric scooters]

Comment: Surely this would depend on the hotel. Why not just ask them?

Comment: Where do you park it? Have you never owned a bike that got stolen? Your possessions *go with you*. I thought this was going to be about the ones you can rent (which I hate, so you can just dump it on the curb, IDC, because that's how they showed up day 1 with no provision otherwise).

Comment: As for recharging, can't you take off the battery?

Comment: Aren't such scooters usually foldable?

Comment: @gerrit you can fold all but just a few models have removable (secondary) batteries. But some aren't as removable as one could think.

Comment: I assume it's the same for bicycles.?

Comment: @Max Depending on the hotel, bikes may go in a garage, court, dining room, shed, garden or sometimes (if the room is big enough) your bedroom. In most European small hotels, it will be hard to impossible to get a bike into the bedrooms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Few points from experience....

- They wouldn't be any dirtier than the wheels on luggage, wheelchair or **an ECV** (Electric Conveyance Vehicle).
- I haven't had a problem taking my scooter most places.  Except....

  - One office building would not allow anything with wheels (even luggage...?), another said the rule is only against rubber tires (this is somewhat understandable as they can more easily mark the very, very glossy floor)
  - A table service restaurant though it might be a tripping hazard, but offered to keep it behind the valet booth.
- I've walked it into some hotels for meetings without issue.
- For hotels, these are no different than luggage carts, hand-trucks, wheelchairs, ECVs, kick scooters or a dozen other things guests might roll in with.

I ride a [Glion Dolly](https://glion-scooter.com/dolly/) which is foldable with a built in handle and roller-wheels.  A custom cover is also available.

Comment: What's an ECV?.

Comment: I looked up the (now full version) and found a lot of pictures of the kind of electric 'wheelchairs' which people use who can walk a little. ECV seemed to trigger a Disney link.

Answer (score 4):

Take a bag which can cover the wheels, either one big one or two smaller ones and you can carry it into your hotel room in almost all hotels.
If you use them in places where they get extremely dirty, you can bring a brush or ask the hotel for a rag and some water to clean them up a bit.

I expect many hotels will be happy to have you leave it somewhere like the hotel's garage, but it will be hard to lock an item as small as this in such a way a thief will find it hard to take it out.
And luggage rooms are meant for luggage, and some will get pretty much filled to the brim at times and an odd shaped item may get in the way.

Charging will likely not be a problem in modern hotels. In older ones, you may have to check with the hotel that the wiring is not going to be a risk.

I do have experience with (recumbent) bikes and trikes in hotels, most are very happy to help you. But there is no standard solution. My bikes and trikes will not fit in the average hotel room, your scooter will.
I have used a human powered scooter in about this size and I know it is not hard to store them in a smallish room.

Answer (score 0):

In hotels your e-scooter can be treated like any large piece of luggage that guests may bring to be carried to their rooms on the hotels trollies, particularly if you have it in a bag or case that conceals it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/145960)